# solve this Quadratic Equation in C++

Tags: c++

y = Ax;
x^2 + y^2 = B;

Thank you.........

Answer (score 3):

Don't need C++, just simple substitution and algebra:

```
y = Ax
x = sqrt(B/(A^2+1))
```